# Is it possible to change Cordova's allow-navigation in config.xml at runtime?

Tags: cordova

Is it possible to change Cordova's allow-navigation in config.xml at runtime?

I was not sure if programatically modifying the config.xml and having it take effect instantly was possible.  It seems like there is no API for setting such a whitelist.

The reasoning behind this is that we want to load on-prem content and that server name can change.  We would like to ensure, however, that nothing could happen that could redirect the user away from that server.  That server is not known a build time, but later configured.  The page may load plugins, so it can't be an in-app-browser.

Answer (score 0):

I should have searched for white listing.  This appears to be a dupe of:
[How to dynamically change Cordova whitelist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42853685/how-to-dynamically-change-cordova-whitelist)

It looks like the only way is to allow everything and then apply my own filter.